# Can AWS Lambda function call an endpoint over a VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, vpn, amazon-vpc

I'm using an SMS sending service provided by a local mobile carrier.
The carrier enforces clients to connect to their datacentre over a VPN in order to reach their endpoints. The VPN tunnel must always be kept open (i.e. not on demand).

Currently, I'm using a micro EC2 instance that acts as middleware between my main production server (also an EC2 instance) and the carrier endpoint.

Production Server --> My SMS Server --over VPN--> Carrier SMS Server

Is there a way to replace my middleware server with an AWS Lambda function that sends HTTP requests to the carrier over an always-on VPN tunnel?

Also, can an AWS Lambda function maintain a static IP?
The carrier has to place my IP in their whitelist before I can use their service.

Comment: No, AWS Lambda functions cannot have static IPs. if they route outbound traffic through NAT then the NAT device could have a static IP.

Comment: @gusto2
The micro EC2 instance has 2 purposes.
1) VPN client to carrier's VPN server.
2) Web API server (takes requests from main production server, then forwards request to carrier's endpoint)

Comment: The carrier needs your VPN gateway IP or the internal IP from the VPC? Maybe they could allow whole subnet?

Comment: the public IP of the EC2 instance needs to be static so they can whitelist it

Comment: And you want to replace the micro-instance with a lambda? How do you plan to keep VPN up? Default AWS Site-to-site VPN?

Comment: @gusto2 s2svpn would be great but my question is can a lambda function HTTP request route through that connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> s2svpn would be great but my question is can a lambda function HTTP request route through that connection?

Sure. Lambdas can have a VPC subnet attached. It's a matter of configuring the subnet routing table / VPN configuration to route the traffic to the carrier through the VPN endpoint.

> Also, can an AWS Lambda function maintain a static IP?

No. Depends. A VPC-attached Lambda will create an eni (network interface) in the subnet with internal (not fixed) subnet iP address. But the traffic can be routed though a fixed NAT or a VPN gateway.

That's the reason I asked which IP address needs to be fixed, on what level. The VPN has a fixed IP address. If the carrier enforces the VPN address whitelisting, lambda clients should be working. If a fixed IP of the internal network is required then you will need a fixed network interface (e.g. using EC2)